# What's a correct way of using HoloEverywhere

Tags: android, android-holo-everywhere

I'm trying to use **dev branch** of HoloEverywhere library to in my app. I understood that this is still during development but the demo seems to work okay so I give it a try.

I put **android:theme="@style/Holo.Theme.Sherlock.Light"** in the activity in my manifest. The structure of the activity is that it's using Fragment, one is a list and another is just Fragment. The ActionBar looks Holo just fine.

I turned my **SherlockFragmentActivity** into **SActivity** and **Fragment** into **SFragment**. Just as I checked in the accompanied demo app. I open dialog using this block of code in my SFragment.

```
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
    builder.setTitle("Work in Progress")
            .setView(inflater.inflate(R.layout.extra_input))
            .setIcon(R.drawable.icon);
    builder.setPositiveButton("Positive", null);
    builder.setNegativeButton("Negative", null);
    builder.setNeutralButton("Neutral", null);
    builder.show();
```

The dialog popped up looking like the OS's AlertDialog where EditText inside extra_input layout shown as Holo. **ProgressDialog** also display with OS's theme as well.

I believed this is me incorrectly implemented the library. The question is how to do it right?

Edit: Solved it, I need to use **com.WazaBe.HoloEverywhere.app.AlertDialog** instead of **android.app.AlertDialog**. Silly me.

Comment: Add your solution as an answer and accept it after the correct amount of time has elapsed.  This allows the question to still be valid in a Q&A format.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Solved it, I need to use **com.WazaBe.HoloEverywhere.app.AlertDialog** instead of **android.app.AlertDialog**. Silly me.

Answer added as recommended.

Comment: what do you do to the manifest in the theme attribute of the activity/application ? does the library has something of its own?

Answer (score 0):

`android:theme="@style/Holo.Theme.Light"`

or in style.xml

`<style name="MyTheme" parent="Holo.Theme.Light">
</style>`