# What should I use for the Android context here?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-context

I'm trying to use this code from "Android Recipes":

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
builder.setTitle("FetchAndPopTask.doInBackground exception");
builder.setMessage(e.getMessage());
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
builder.create().show();
```

...but don't know what I should replace "context" with. I've tried the .java file's class, the immediate class, and "this" but none of them compile.

In more context, the code is:

```
public class SQLiteActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private FetchAndPopTask _fetchAndPopTask;

. . .

private class FetchAndPopTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        . . .
        try {
            . . .
        } catch (Exception e) {
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this); // <= "context"...?
            builder.setTitle("If I go blind, I'll use a Service Platypus (instead of a Service Dog)");
            builder.setMessage(e.getMessage());
            builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
            builder.create().show();
            return result;
    }
```

I tried all of the following:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(SQLiteActivity);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(FetchAndPopTask);
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

...but none compile; so what does "context" need to be here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`doInBackground()` will be run on a background thread. You cannot touch your UI on a non-UI thread. This includes displaying dialogs. Remove the `AlertDialog` from `doInBackground()`. You can put it in e.g. `onPostExecute()` that runs on UI thread. In there you can use `YourActivityName.this` to refer to the outer class `this` to be used as a `Context`.

Answer (score 3):

`AlertDialog.Builder(SQLiteActivity.this)` should probably work

But take a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16591536/actionbarsherlock-doesnt-support-light-theme-alert-dialogs)

**EDIT!!!!!**
Sorry, didn't notice you're trying to *show* it in non-UI thread. Please place it in constructor or in `onPreExecute()`/`onPostExecute()` methods

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass an `Activity` to this constructor.

You have to add this in the `FetchAndPopTask` class:

```
private SQLiteActivity context;

public FetchAndPopTask(SQLiteActivity context) {
    this.context = context;
}
```

Then, in the `SQLiteActivity` class, you have to pass this context by using `this` keyword (as you are in an activity, it refers to it):

```
/*...*/
FetchAndPopTask task = new FetchAndPopTask(this);
task.execute();
/*...*/
```

Comment: You can see that async task class is non-static so you can use 'SQLiteActivity.this' to be shorter

Comment: @SamN-a I did not know that. Indeed it is shorter and more convenient. Thanks ;)

Comment: Would not say it's more convenient because it may cause some extra work when refactoring(when you put the asynctask out of this class, for example). However it's shorter ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
```

the `this` means that you are getting the pointer/reference of `FetchAndPopTask` so instead of using `this` use the pointer/reference of your `SQLiteActivity` by calling `SQLiteActivity.this`

Answer (score 1):

Define a constructor for your class and pass the context there

```
private class FetchAndPopTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

private Context mContext;

public FetchAndPopTask(Context context){
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
    . . .
    try {
        . . .
    } catch (Exception e) {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext); // <= use the variable here
        builder.setTitle("If I go blind, I'll use a Service Platypus (instead of a Service Dog)");
        builder.setMessage(e.getMessage());
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);
        builder.create().show();
        return result;
}
```